# Next Largest Value in a Binary Tree Value

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

Given a node, to find the next largest value, there are two cases:

- First: if the node has a right child. If it does, then the next largest value is located at the left-most of the left subtree of its right child.
- Second: if the node is a leaf, then the next largest value is in one of its parents. Which parent is it though?

Thanks!

Comment: SO is not a place where we do your homework for you. We can give you general guidance, but we're not going to give you the answer to your homework. Show us what you've done so far, and we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: There's no need to be condescending. The question comes across as a homework question. Perhaps if you had mentioned in your question everything that you wrote to me in your comment, you wouldn't be sitting at -6 votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first case is entirely correct. The second case, however, should be replaced with this:

2) If the node has no right child (note: this does not mean it is a leaf!), then you have to wonder up the (unique) path from the node to the root until you encouter a parent which is larger than its child. That parent is the next larger node. If no such parent exists, then the node we started with is the largest node in the tree.

Comment: A node can have only one parent. I assume you meant, “predecessor”, right?